# overriding hashCode, why is this.hashCode() not used?

Tags: java, overriding, hashcode

When overriding the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in Java why isn't this used often:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) this.hashCode();
}
```

Or even the above with a prime introduced:

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31; //31 is a common example
    return (int) prime * this.hashCode();
}
```

Is this bad practise or does this just simply not work?

Comment: Why don't you try it? What do you think this.hashCode() will do, except calling this.hashCode(), which will call this.hashCode(), which will call this.hashCode(), etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) this.hashCode();
}
```

would lead to an `StackOverflowError` because it recurse into itself infinitely, unless you replace `this` with `super`. Your second method has the same problem.

In addition, casting a value of type `int` into an `int` is useless as well.

If you do not provide anything useful new to a method, just don't override it.

Comment: Either of the OP's posted ones would cause this, not just the first.

Comment: Aha I see, I only wish to override the hashCode because I want to get rid of the error, so would `super.hashCode()` make sense for this?

Comment: There is no need to override `hashCode()` in your examples, because you do not change any significant behavior. The value of the new `hashCode()` is still based on the value of the new hashCode(). You need or would like to change `hashCode()` when you change the behavior of `equals()` because of the contract: `If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.`